# Laravel - What is the best practice to store status of an upload/action? Such as uploading profile picture

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, eloquent, relationship

Assuming there is application where Users can be informed of their status of pending or complete actions, what would be the best way to solve this.

For example, prompting the users to upload a profile picture if they have not done so and/or notifiying them the action is complete.

One way would be to use upload_status fields in the user table, but is it the best way to handle this?

Comment: You could use [`Queue`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues)

Comment: That would be handle in the front-end, how do you know when the image is uploaded ? When the browser finishes uploading it. And then, if the endpoint returns a `200` or other HTTP code, handle it as success or fail... It has nothing to do with the backend...

Answer (score 1):

Using the user table wouldn't allow users to have more than one pending upload. Besides that, that solution doesn't feel normalized. However, a simple solution would be the `Session`:

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('upload', [ UploadController::class, 'upload' ]);
Route::get('upload-status/{upload}', [ UploadController::class, 'uploadStatus' ]);
```

app\Http\Controllers\UploadController.php ([`require spatie/async`](https://github.com/spatie/async))

```php
use Spatie\Async\Pool;

class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $sessionKey = 'upload-'.Auth::id().'-'.time();
        Session::set($sessionKey, 'pending');

        $pool[] = async(function () use ($i) {
            // upload magic
        })->then(function (int $output) use($sessionKey) {
            Session::set($sessionKey, 'done');
        })->catch(function ($exception) {
            Session::set($sessionKey, 'failed');
        });

        return $sessionKey
    }

    public function uploadStatus(string $upload)
    {
        return Session::get($upload);
    }
}
```

Haven't tested the code. It's just how I would start (more or less pseudocode). But maybe it helps.

---

Alternatively, here's a client-side solution:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// listen for `load` event
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(`The transfer is completed: ${xhr.status} ${xhr.response}`);
};

// listen for `error` event
xhr.onerror = () => {
    console.error('Download failed.');
}

// listen for `abort` event
xhr.onabort = () => {
    console.error('Download cancelled.');
}

// listen for `progress` event
xhr.onprogress = (event) => {
    // event.loaded returns how many bytes are downloaded
    // event.total returns the total number of bytes
    // event.total is only available if server sends `Content-Length` header
    console.log(`Upload ${event.loaded} of ${event.total} bytes`);
}

// open and send request
xhr.open('POST', '{{ url('upload') }}');
xhr.send();
```

---

If you want to work with [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), you can use this:

```js
axios.post('{{ url('upload') }}', data, {
  onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
    let percentCompleted = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
    // do whatever you like with the percentage complete
    // maybe dispatch an action that will update a progress bar or something
  })
        .then(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: The front-end has to handle this with simple AJAX requests... this is overkill for a simple task as such.

Comment: I added an alternative client-side solution

Comment: Good one, simple recommendation, as we are using Laravel, use [`Axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) as it is already implemented and is easier to use (your solution is not hard, but is vanilla)

Comment: It's now included in the answer

Comment: Does session get stored permamently? the data is lost once the session ends.